# Kernel build 4.4.0.22 decreases battery life (16.04 LTS)

Tags: kernel, 16.04, power-management, battery, amd-graphics

My battery life was fine when I installed 16.04 LTS (clean install) on my Lenovo z51-70, but after a regular software update or build to kernel, from **4.4.0.21 to 4.4.0.22**, it has almost halved (1.50 hours compared to 3 hours standby time).

Now I know I can still cause the older one, and I have made it default in Grub customizer, but what is the cause of this? It's only kernel build, LTS. Problem persists though, when upgrading to other LTS and mainline kernels.

I'm using TLP and attaching the output. This is quite annoying, especially if I can expect it in further builds. Anyone encountered similar problems?

I use hybrid-graphics with powersaving Intel i915 and discreet ATI Radeon GPU.

**uname -a:**

```
Linux gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**tlp stat:**

```
--- TLP 0.8 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=powersave
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="radeon nouveau"
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO Lenovo Z51-70 80K6
BIOS           = C2CN19WW(V2.00)
Release        = Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Kernel         = 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic root=UUID=0739d2c4-9774-41f4-bd8c-b7bd3ee7c53c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Init system    = systemd

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = battery

+++ Processor
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   500000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2700000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   500000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2700000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   500000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2700000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   500000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2700000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      = 18
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 0

x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = powersave
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = powersave
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = powersave
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = powersave

/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    54 [°C]
Fan speed (fan1)       =   257 [/min]

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     2
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  6000
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  6000
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/age_buffer_centisecs  = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs    = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfsbufd_centisecs     = (not available)

+++ Storage Devices
/dev/sda:
          Model     = Patriot Blaze                           
          Firmware  = S9FM02.3
          APM Level = 128
          Status    = active/idle
          TRIM      = supported
          Scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            9 Power_On_Hours            =     2187 [h]
          194 Temperature_Celsius       =       30    [°C]
          241 Total_LBAs_Written        =    0.001 [TB]


+++ SATA Aggressive Link Power Management
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy  = min_power

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = default (using bios preferences)

+++ Intel Graphics
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6       =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc       = -1 (use per-chip default)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock   = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores       = -1 (use per-chip default)

+++ Radeon Graphics
/sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_state = battery
/sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level = off

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = off (software)
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

hci0(btusb)         : not connected
wlp3s0(iwlwifi)     : connected, power management = on

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 1
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = Y

+++ Runtime Power Management
device classes   = all
device blacklist = (not configured)
driver blacklist = radeon nouveau

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, bdw_uncore)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = auto (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, i915)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control = auto (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = auto (0x078000, Communication controller, mei_me)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.4/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = auto (0x0c0320, USB controller, ehci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = auto (0x060100, ISA bridge, lpc_ich)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = auto (0x010601, SATA controller, ahci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = auto (0x0c0500, SMBus, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control = auto (0x020000, Ethernet controller, r8169)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control = auto (0x028000, Network controller, iwlwifi)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/power/control = auto (0x038000, Display controller, radeon)

+++ USB
autosuspend        = enabled
device whitelist   = (not configured)
device blacklist   = (not configured)
wwan blacklist     = enabled

Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:8001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp.  (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 005 ID 8087:07dc control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Intel Corp.  (btusb)
Bus 002 Device 004 ID 04f2:b50f control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd  (uvcvideo)
Bus 002 Device 003 ID 0bda:0129 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller (rtsx_usb)
Bus 002 Device 002 ID 046d:c52f control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver (usbhid)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = LENOVO 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = PABAS0241231
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design             =  31680 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full                    =  23680 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now                     =  23650 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now                      =   1462 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Discharging
```

Also, to see which graphics driver is in use in both kernels:

lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

(INtel).

Looking at sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:04:00.0
```

Powertop doesn't list anything different between the 4.4.0.21 and 22:

[image]

though I don't know about what to do here:

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Lenovo z51-70 uses an intel i5-5200U CPU. Could you provide turbostat summary output for both kernels?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: So, for otherwise similar conditions, provide the output for both kernels for `sudo turbostat --debug sleep 300` (you can use a lesser sleep time than 5 minutes if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's AMDGPU problem. Radeon is draining battery and pushing CPU to the limits, thus decreasing battery life. I disabled it in BIOS, selecting "Use UMA graphics". I belive I'll wait for the AMDGPU to progress a bit more and then use it again.